# Dealing with Transaction (Process ID X) was deadlocked on lock

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, ado.net

I get the following error message on a query on SQL Server 2016 - ADO.NET Connection

Exception message: Transaction (Process ID 358) was deadlocked on lock | communication buffer resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.

```
SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE EXISTS ( 
                       SELECT * FROM Table1 
                      WHERE Id = '1234' 
                      AND SourceId = Table1.[Id]);
```

What could be possibly causing the issue ?

What is the scope of the shared/read lock that gets created when this query is run ?   ie, is the shared lock applied on entire Table2 or just the rows in the result set ? (I am asking this because this looks like a correlated subquery)

Will refactoring this to INNER JOIN will help?

```
SELECT t2.* FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN  Table1 t1
ON t2.SourceId = b.Id
WHERE t1.Id = '1234'
```

From logs I not see any other update statements updating the result set(or the table) +/- 10 seconds when error occurred.

So will multiple users running the same query create deadlock ? (there are no non clustered index on the table)

Will speeding up the query using indexing strategy help with deadlock situation ?
Table has 2 Million records and is not indexed properly (it just has a primary key (not SourceId )). I see an Index scan in the execution plan. Hence adding a non clustered index on SourceId covering  other columns help ?
I see that this will require additional 400 MB on space for index data structure. So I would not ideally want to do it. 
Will adding a non clustered index on SourceId (not covering index) help ?(due to space constrains)

Default Isolation level for our application is Repeated Read. Will relaxing the isolation level by using WITH (NOLOCK) help ?

How do I know which is the other SQL statement which is conflicting with this ? Is it OK to run SQL Profiler in Production database to generate the DeadLock graph ?

What else is recommended to identify and fix the issue ?

Comment: Deadlocks store information within the database as a deadlock graph, to know exactly what is happening you need to access that information. You're also probably better off asking that question on https://dba.stackexchange.com. For large, complex databases deadlocks can be hard to avoid, you often need to implement a retry strategy to handle the case when they happen.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/analyze-deadlocks-with-sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: "Will speeding up the query using indexing strategy help with deadlock situation ? " - Yes, almost always.

Comment: At first you should enable TF 1222 in order to write the deadlock information to the error log. Furthermore, try reading and implementing what is written here https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/building-custom-blocked-process-report/

Comment: @DarkoMartinovic - is there any possible negative repercussions for enabling trace 1222 in production system  (for around 6 hours)?

Comment: As far as I know NO.

Answer (score 0):

reducing isolation level does not help with locked user.. but helps the other users whom uses locked tables.. reducing isolation level to Read Uncommitted does same effect with No Lock statements in each table.